# aws cognito with facebook login? - android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

so im really confused on how the facebook login works with aws cognito in android. I was able to hook aws cognito up and the facebook log in just fine. The aws cognito guide gives me these lines of code:

```
 Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
        logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

couple questions:
1.Where do i put these lines of code?
2.How do i set up cognito user equal to the login facebook user?
3.And basically, whats a working example of this?

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the following code where I have used the facebook login with federated identities from the congnito. first you need to set up the CognitoSyncManagerFile with the appropriate login credentials with the pool details . And then the following code as follows .

```
//initialize the facebook SDK 
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

 //If access token is already here, set fb session
        final AccessToken fbAccessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (fbAccessToken != null) {
            setFacebookSession(fbAccessToken);
        //    btnLoginFacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

btnLoginFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFacebook);
        btnLoginFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start Facebook Login
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
                LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        btnLoginFacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        new GetFbName(loginResult).execute();
                        setFacebookSession(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Facebook login cancelled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in Facebook login " +
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });





//Set the session with the following method
      private void setFacebookSession(AccessToken accessToken) {
                Log.i(TAG, "facebook token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                CognitoSyncClientManager.addLogins("graph.facebook.com",
                        accessToken.getToken());


            }
```

For more information follow the below url

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

Comment: after this , am able to login but unable to register in AWS.

Comment: @GvSharma I am facing same issue can you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put this in a spot where your credentials provider has already been initialized, where you have just logged in to Facebook for the user in question.
2. Once you have included this in the logins map, call credentialsProvider.refresh(). This will link the login to the user's identity.
3. The official [AWS samples repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) has an android sample that does all this.

Comment: link not working!! Please guide me how to add facebook user in user pool